# Call Winphone method in unity with Ngui

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, unity-game-engine, ngui

I am using Ngui in unity

I have written event Button OnClick in NGui

```
    void OnClick()
    {             
        if (gameObject.name == "More Game")
        {
            if (ShowMoreGame!= null)
            {
                ShowMoreGame(gameObject, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
```

In Winphone,I have written code :

```
    private void Unity_Loaded()
    {  
        Menuclick more = (Menuclick)UnityEngine.Object.FindObjectOfType(typeof(Menuclick));
        more.ShowMoreGame+= lisGame;
    }

    void lisGame(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate
        {
            MarketplaceSearchTask mkSearch = new MarketplaceSearchTask();                
            mkSearch.SearchTerms = "dev";
            mkSearch.Show();

        });
    }
```

It's not working

Comment: "not working" is not a problem description

Comment: one me click Button "More Game" not working

Comment: You need to elaborate on the "not working" part. What code runs, what doesn't? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Are you sure that ShowMoreGame is an object (class) rather than a method because testing for a method not being null is not possible.

Comment: ShowMoreGame is event .
i initialize in class Menuclick on Unity
public  event EventHandler ShowMoreGame;

Comment: event "ShowMoreGame " null,why so?

Comment: if I wirte in OnMouseUp() is ShowMoreGame!=null

Comment: @LearnCocos2D help me